# Safest way to store API KEYS using Firebase (Remote config/Firestore)

Tags: android, firebase, security

First of all, I do understand that any API KEY that is on the client side can be stolen. API KEY is used for specific 3rd party backend services. I have a way of re-generating API KEY when I detect that someone has stolen it, but I want to make it as hard as possible for people to steal it.

I'm currently thinking to store the API KEY on Firebase Remote Configuration and access it after user logs in. Is there a way of making hackers life miserable to catch it when we download remote configuration data to the client side? Or at least make it tiny bit complicated so they avoid abusing it?

P.S. I do plan to move API KEY to Server Side later on, but for MVP I want to find a way that makes it little bit more safe than hard-coding it and bundling it with the app itself.

Comment: The [Remote Config documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config) is quite clear on this: "Don't store confidential data in Remote Config parameter keys or parameter values. Remote Config data is encrypted in transit, but end users can access any default or fetched Remote Config parameter that is available to their client app instance."